# Properly dispose SendMailAsync with PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, asynchronous

I have a PowerShell script that can send an email notification when certain things happen. I didn't want to have this lock the script up, so I decided to send it asynchronously. However, it's typically best practice to dispose the resources being used, especially when I have attachments and streams being used.

There are plenty of resources out on the internet and SO on how to do this directly with C#, but I'm not sure if there is a way to do it with PowerShell without resorting to writing a DLL and running that from within the script.

This is what I currently have. It does send the desired emails, and does so asynchronously, but I'm not sure if the resources are being disposed properly, and if they're not - how to do so.

```
$fromaddress = 'Analysis Alert <me@email.com>'
$toaddress = 'them@email.com'
$subject = "Analysis report for <selected>"
$body = "Attached is a report for the anomaly(ies) detected."
$smtpserver = 'smtp.myserver.com'

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$attached = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment -ArgumentList $attachpath
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver)
$message.From = $fromaddress
$message.To.Add($toaddress)
$message.Subject = $subject
$message.Body = $body
$message.Attachments.Add($attached)
$smtp.SendMailAsync($message)
```

Comment: You can try something like this https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/using-object-powershell-version-of-cs-using-statement/ or you can call $smtp.Dispose(); $attached.Dispose() and $message.Dispose(); - But powershell does clean up after a while. IMO disposing is good practice